# GNU make: foreach behave different in defined and outside

Tags: makefile

I am trying to write a custom "function" in GNU Makefile. However, The "$(foreach" function behaves differently between inside "defined" and outside

Makefile steps:

1. Define current folder is "."
2. Get all the sub-folders
3. For each sub-folder, add the suffix "-subdir"

```
define get_folders
dirs:=$(dir $(wildcard $(1)/*/))
test_function:=$(foreach subdir,$$(dirs), $(subdir)"-subdir")
endef

CURRENT_FOLDER:=.
dirs:=$(dir $(wildcard $(CURRENT_FOLDER)/*/))
test_outside:=$(foreach subdir,$(dirs), $(subdir)"-subdir")

.PHONNY:test_function
test_function:
        $(eval $(call get_folders,$(CURRENT_FOLDER)))
        @echo "in-function" $(test_function)
        @echo "outside" $(test_outside)
```

when I run the make, following is printed out:

```
in-function ./header/ ./Tools/-subdir
outside ./header/-subdir ./Tools/-subdir
```

As you can see, the result of commands outside are as I expected but for the in-function, it seems that all sub-folders are considered one string so only one suffix was added

Can you please kindly explain me why it happened this way and how can I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem comes from the way make expands your recipe. `$(eval ...)` first expands its parameter (`$(call get_folders,$(CURRENT_FOLDER))`). If you try to imagine the result you'll understand that the first line of your macro expands as:

```
dirs:=./header/ ./Tools/
```

But consider the second line:

```
test_function:=$(foreach subdir,$$(dirs), $(subdir)"-subdir")
```

The `foreach` will iterate only once, on the `$(dirs)` token, leading to:

```
test_function:=$(dirs)"-subdir"
```

Thus the result you observe. Try this, instead:

```
define get_folders
dirs:=$(dir $(wildcard $(1)/*/))
test_function:=$(foreach subdir,$(dirs), $(subdir)"-subdir")
endef
```

Note that mixing make and shell programming in your recipes is not ideal. It is difficult to understand, maintain and debug. You could as well separate the two worlds:

```
define get_folders
dirs:=$$(dir $$(wildcard $(1)/*/))
test_function:=$$(foreach subdir,$$(dirs), $$(subdir)"-subdir")
endef

CURRENT_FOLDER:=.
$(eval $(call get_folders,$(CURRENT_FOLDER)))

.PHONY:test_function
test_function:
    @echo "in-function" $(test_function)
```

The `$$` in the macro are used to escape the first expansion by `eval`, leading to:

```
dirs:=$(dir $(wildcard ./*/))
test_function:=$(foreach subdir,$(dirs), $(subdir)"-subdir")
```

If you plan to use this macro with several `CURRENT_FOLDER` values you can pass it a second parameter to personalize the variable names and avoid conflicts:

```
# $(1): current folder
# $(2): variable names prefix
define get_folders
$(2)-dirs:=$$(dir $$(wildcard $(1)/*/))
$(2)-subdirs:=$$(foreach subdir,$$($(2)-dirs), $$(subdir)"-subdir")
endef

CURRENT_FOLDER:=.
$(eval $(call get_folders,$(CURRENT_FOLDER),test_function))

.PHONY:test_function
test_function:
    @echo "in-function" $($@-subdirs)
```

Even better, you could turn `CURRENT_FOLDER` into a target-specific variable:

```
# $(1): current folder
# $(2): variable names prefix
define get_folders
$(2)-dirs    = $$(dir $$(wildcard $(1)/*/))
$(2)-subdirs = $$(foreach subdir,$$($(2)-dirs),$$(subdir)"-subdir")
endef

$(eval $(call get_folders,$$(CURRENT_FOLDER),test_function))

.PHONY:test_function
test_function: CURRENT_FOLDER = .

test_function:
    @echo "in-function" $($@-subdirs)
```